# Move 1st Div to 2nd Div on responsive

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design, css-position

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
}

.class1 {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

.class2 {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="class1">
    The First Thing
  </div>

  <div class="class2">
    The Second Thing
  </div>
  
</div>
```

How to move the first div "class1" to be after second div "class2" on tablet view? Do I have to change the position and set manually using top? Is there any other way than that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `order`, with media queries.

```css
.box {
  display: block;
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
}

.class1 {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

.class2 {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 531px) {
  .box {
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column;
  }
  .class2 {
    order: 1;
  }
  .class1 {
    order: 2;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="class1">
    The First Thing
  </div>

  <div class="class2">
    The Second Thing
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use Media Queries and flex order.

```css
.box {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  padding: 20px;
  background: black;
  display:flex;
  flex-flow:column;
}

.class1 {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

.class2 {
  position: relative;
  color: red;
}

@media(max-width: 768px) {
    .class1 {
       order: 2;
    }
    .class2 {
       order: 1;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="box">

  <div class="class1">
    The First Thing
  </div>

  <div class="class2">
    The Second Thing
  </div>
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid layout.  Bootstrap, PrimeNg, and many other frameworks have them.

Comment: This should be a comment. not an answer

Answer (score 0):

If you are using bootstrap, we can do this.

```html
<div class="order-2 order-md-1">detail</div>
<div class="order-1 order-md-2">photo</div>
```

When in desktop size `detail` will be on the left

When in mobile size `detail` will be on the bottom

Answer (score -1):

```
.box {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row | column
}

@media screen and (...) {
  .box {
     flex-direction: row-reverse | column-reverse
  }
}
```